# Инкапсуляция в Python

Tags: python, ооп, python-3.x

Допустим у меня имеется вот такой класс:

```
class Bunch_of_comments():
    def __init__(self, *list_of_comments, date=datetime.now()):
        self.date = date

        self.list_of_comments = []
        self.comments_counter = 0

        self.list_of_comments.append(list_of_comments)
        self.comments_counter += len(list_of_comments)
```

Я хочу сделать в нем геттер по списку `list_of_comments`. Вот такое действие

```
def get_list_of_comments(self):
    return self.get_list_of_comments() # don't forget to find out about return value
```

нарушит инкапсуляцию, т.к. возвращается ссылка на список, а это значит, что тот кто принимает его может делать с ним все, что захочет, например, добавлять в него элементы без сеттера.

Что же делать ?

Comment: Все поля в питоне публичные, поэтому если кто-нибудь захочет изменить ваш массив, то он просто сделает так: `obj.list_of_comments = [1, 2, 3]` или даже так `obj.list_of_comments = "Bla Bla Bla"`.

Comment: Что же делать ? Нельзя ли их как-нибудь сделать закрытыми ?

Comment: Сделать этого нельзя. В питоне есть соглашение, что поля в именах которых в начале стоит двойное подчеркивание `__name` нужно считать приватными, но на самом деле они все равно будут публичными и любой их сможет поменять. Ничего не - поделаешь такой язык.

Comment: Я не понимаю. В Python получается вообще нет сеттеров и геттеров, а обращение напрямую к полям считается нормой ?

Comment: В Python и глобальные переменные норма. Это скриптовый язык. Что вы от него хотите. [Тут](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) можно почитать о классах в Python.

Comment: Я хочу грамотно построить класс, вот и все.

Comment: Программируя на Python, вам на время придется поменять отношение к классам. Здесь классы не такие как в Java или C++. Еще вот [это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) возможно будет полезным.

Comment: Еще один небольшой вопрос. Я так и не понял, раз инкапсуляции в явном виде в Python нет, то надо делать геттеры и сеттеры или это не принято и я буду быдлокодером, если их сделаю ? Мне не хватает практического опыта в программировании на Python... :)

Comment: У меня опыт программирования на Python тоже не такой уж большой. Можете поизучать проекты на [github](https://github.com/trending/python). Писать геттеры, я думаю, имеет смысл только когда получение значения какой-то переменной занимает время. Например, перед возвратом вы можете проверить значение на корректность.

Comment: Геттеры, сеттеры и делитеры имеют право на существование. Но в Питоне их используют не по умолчанию для всех случаев, а тогда, когда в этом есть конкретный смысл. Иногда всё-таки стоит прикрыть внутреннюю механику каким-то интерфейсом.

Comment: используйте: `self.list_of_comments += list_of_comments`  вместо `self.list_of_comments.append(list_of_comments)` последнее делает список вложенным (списком списков с комментариями).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно возвращать не сам список, а его копию (либо поверхностную, либо глубокую).

Это гарантирует, что внешний пользователь класса случайно не порушит его внутреннюю механику.

Но, разумеется, если уж он специально озадачится тем, чтобы залезть своими кривыми ручками куда не надо, то он таки туда залезет.
В Питоне это считается нормальным - уж если кто-то осознанно лезет под капот чужого кода, то он считает себя готовым к возможным последствиям.

UPD: Самый простой способ сделать копию списка, это взять его срез без указания границ:

```
copy_list = source_list[:]
```

Этот способ подходит для тех случаев, когда список состоит только из неизменяемых элементов (чисел, строк, кортежей, frozenset и т.п.)

Однако, этот способ не стоит применять, если в список входят изменяемые элементы (другие списки, множества и т.п.) - потому что из копии можно будет менять эти объекты в оригинале. В этом случае нужно использовать глубокую копию:

```
import copy
dcopy_list = copy.deepcopy(source_list)
```

Comment: А как правильно сделать копию списка в Python ?

Comment: faoxis, добавил про то, как делать копии с сам ответ, а то в комментариях пример кода нормально не вставить.

Answer (score 5):

Можно возвращать `iter()` от списка, тогда сам список напрямую изменить будет нельзя (добавлять/удалять/заменять элементы, заменить список на другой; хотя если элементы изменяемые, можно будет повлиять на них). Это лучше, чем возвращение копии списка, т.к. не требует дополнительной памяти под копию.

В вашем случае можно сделать так:

```
class Bunch_of_comments():
   ...

   def get_comments(self):
       return iter(self.list_of_comments)  # возвращаем итератор

comments = Bunch_of_comments()

... # добавляем несколько комментариев

# Выводим список:
for item in comments.get_comments():
    print(item)
```

Нужно помнить, что итератор позволяет только последовательный доступ к элементам (доступ по индексу невозможен). Если нужен доступ по индексу, нужно делать из итератора список.

Если нужна копия списка, можно обернуть вызов этого метода в `list()`:

```
x1 = list(comments.get_comments())
```

Это будет "поверхностная" копия, т.е. сами элементы будут ссылками на элементы исходного списка.

Если нужна "глубокая" копия, можно воспользоваться функцией `copy.deepcopy()`, как показал Александр в своем ответе.

Comment: Хорошее замечание. Добавлю, что нужно в зависимости от конкретного случая выбирать между копией и итератором. Если предполагается, что внутри самого класса список будет непредсказуемо меняться, то итератор может выдавать непредсказуемые результаты.

Comment: А можно небольшой пример функции, которая возвращается iter() ?

Comment: @faoxis: возможно следует `Bunch_of_comments()` в перечислимое значение (iterable) превратить, чтобы можно было прямо в цикле использовать: `def __iter__(self): return iter(self.list_of_comments)`, а потом `for comment in comments: print(comment)`